# Making River/water map with stream order in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, stream-order

I'm a complete novice.
I am using QGIS but am open to trying anything else.

I am trying to make a map like the example at http://www.hydrosheds.org/.

HydroSHEDS provides void filled elevation, hydrologically conditioned elevation, drainage direction, flow accumulation, and a vector of rivers.

With this data I know I should be able to 'easily' output a map like the example.

As a complete beginner I am overwhelmed with the many different ways it seems like you can do this.

What is the most simple way to create an image like the example with this data?

Should I be using a different GIS software?

Should I be using a different data set?

Answer (score 1):

I use routinely the grass-qgis extension and its ''hydrological modelling tool'' to create, accumulation and direction raster and river vectors .
have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKn_CMhDMK0

cheers

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I've figured out how to output the rivers using r.watersheds... but I cannot figure out how to account for stream order/size.  Do you just output at different levels, change to vector, adjust the size on each one?